# HP LaserJet Pro M15w

Tags: printing, hp, laserjet

I downloaded the driver for the HP LaserJet Pro M15w printer on this https://hpdrivers-software.com/hp-laserjet-pro-m15w-driver-software/ , whether this website is safe to use

Comment: Why do you want to download a windows printer driver? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It's not a safe site to use. Use N0rbert's link instead.